# sql show distinct column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table like this and need to add column which will show info only in distinct rows:

```
 ID    Name
 1     1001
 2     1001
 3     1001
 4     1001
 5     1002
 6     1002
 7     1002
 8     1003
 9     1004
10     1004
```

I need such result:

```
 ID    Name    Result
 1     1001    1
 2     1001    NULL
 3     1001    NULL
 4     1001    NULL
 5     1002    1
 6     1002    NULL
 7     1002    NULL
 8     1003    1
 9     1004    1
10     1004    NULL
```

The result column basically selects 1 only for distinct Name values. 
This should be some basic query, but I cannot figure it.

Comment: Does the '1' have to be on the first instance of the distinct value?

Comment: Technically those are all unique rows as they have a different value for ID. Second off why do you want all the ID's but only the first to have the 1 value?

Comment: actually it does not matter if it will be the first which will be marked, or any other row of that same **Name**. This query will be used to form table which I will use in multidimensional cube building, where I need all ID's in place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ordering will wreak havoc with your concept, I'll assume that you'll always sort by ID.

You can do something like this:

```
select ID, Name, 
  case (select count(*) from table t2 where t2.Name=t1.Name and t1.ID > t2.ID)
    when 0 then 1
    else null
  end as Result
from table t1
```

This will count all the rows with the same name, and with a lower ID than the row processed. If there are no such rows, then it's a new name, so it'll get the 1, otherwise, it will get a `null` value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number` to get the first instance of a group, in this case `Name`:

```
select ID, Name,
    case row_number() over(partition by Name order by ID)
        when 1 then 1 end Result
from YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
SELECT ID, 
       NAME, 
       Case When x.minId Is Not Null Then 1 Else Null End As Result
FROM Table
left JOIN (
    SELECT Name, min(id) minId
    FROM Table ) x
    on x.minId = Table.Id
    and x.Name = Table.Name
```